# google cloud engine instance is deleting installed packages

Tags: installation, google-cloud-platform

I posted this also in Stack Overflow:

hi
i am running a google cloud compute instance as a debian jessie machine.
i installed apache and java via apt-get and tomcat via wget from the tomcat repository.
the instance is running and not stopped.
ever since i installed the packages, i notice that at one point, some of the features i installed are removed.
in tomcat, the manager directory is deleted and with it the capability to remote manage the server via the web interface.
also, a WAR i deployed is also deleted.
why is this happening?
i need to constantly remove and re-install the tomcat and re-deploy the WAR file.

is this something related to a snapshot i took of the instance? though when i played with this snapshot, manager application was available under tomcat ROOT.

this is very frustrating. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#os_auto_updates), GCE infrastructure does not automatically update the OS or software in the VMs. Nevertheless, some OS are pre-configured by the vendor to apply security patches and upgrades. If packages were being removed, it could have been a script running inside the VM.

The best way to understand what is happening is by using regular Linux [auditing tools](https://linux-audit.com/configuring-and-auditing-linux-systems-with-audit-daemon/).